# Setting button image and title wont show title

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I am trying to set a button with an image and title aligned vertically so that the title is below the image. Googling says the reason for the button not showing the title is because the image edges are pushing the title off. But when i set the edges i still cant see the title.

My button is set programmatically as follows:

```
private let dislikeButton = UIButton()

dislikeButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
dislikeButton.setTitle(String.Localized.Button.dislike, for: .normal)
dislikeButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
dislikeButton.setImage(UIImage.leftPaw, for: .normal)
dislikeButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 150)
dislikeButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 150, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

The button height is set to 100 and the width to half the screen width.

[image: Button looks like this atm]

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

set to Button custom

```
let dislikeButton = UIButton(type : .custom)
dislikeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `backgroundImage` property of the button.

```swift
dislikeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "your-image-name.jpg"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: this seems to avoid the issue and means i have to set in a work around to scale the image correctly. Also the same for using edge insets on it

Answer (score 0):

This is a ios sdk bug, image's and title's custom insets are working successfully only with fixed width